# pygameで変数がちゃんと動かない。（適応？されない）

Tags: python, python3, macos, pygame

今pygameでゲームを作っているのですが、クラス内で定義したgame_overという名前の変数がメインループでちゃんと動きません（クラス内で`True`にしたけど、メインループでは`False`のまま）

一応クラスの外で変数を定義したときには、クラス内でうまく動きませんでした。
わかる方いましたらご回答よろしくお願いします。

問題のクラス

```
#ハート（HP)のクラス---------------------------------------------------
class Heart():
    game_over = False
    
    heart_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_heart.png')
    heart_img = pygame.transform.scale(heart_img,(64,64))
    font = pygame.font.Font('DotGothic16-Regular.ttf',50)
    text_HP = font.render('HP',True,WHITE)
    heart = 4

    def update(self):
        screen.blit(self.text_HP,(30,100))
        if self.heart == 4:
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(10,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(55,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(100,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(145,160))
        
        if self.heart == 3:
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(10,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(55,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(100,160))

        if self.heart == 2:
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(10,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(55,160))

        if self.heart == 1:
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(10,160))

        if self.heart == 0:
            gameover.gameowari()
            self.game_over = True
        print(Heart.game_over)

        

            

#------------------------------------------------------------------
```

全コード

```
import pygame
from setting import *
import time
import random



pygame.init()

#ウィンドウの設定---------
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 800

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('石よけよ！')
#-------------

#明るさのクラス--------------------------------
class Backgrou():
    alpha = 0     
    Bacgro_time = 0
    def trans(self):

        if self.Bacgro_time == 42:
            #print(self.alpha)
            self.Bacgro_time = 0
            self.alpha += 1
            
    def Background_time(self, surface):
        self.Bacgro_time += 1
        img = pygame.image.load('黒い四角形3.png').convert_alpha()
        rect = img.get_rect(center=(400,400))
        img.set_alpha(self.alpha)
        surface.blit(img, rect)

#-------------------------------------------------

#プレイヤーのクラス-----------------------------------------------------------------
class PlayerSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    player_time = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(PlayerSprite, self).__init__()

        self.images = list()
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_0.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_1.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_2.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_3.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_4.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('bouningen_hasiru/sprite_5.png'))
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        

    def update(self):
        self.player_time += 1

        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        if self.player_time == 4:
            self.index += 1
            self.player_time = 0
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(player_x,670))
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (256,256))


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#背景（周りの草）のクラス---------------------------------------------------------------

class KusaSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    kusa_time = 0
    kusa_time2 = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(KusaSprite,self).__init__()

        self.images = list()
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa0.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa1.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa2.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa3.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa4.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa5.png'))
        self.index = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.image2 = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        

    def update(self):
        self.kusa_time += 1

        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0


        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        if self.kusa_time == 5:
            self.index += 1
            self.kusa_time = 0
        
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(200,800))


class KusaSprite2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    kusa_time = 0
    kusa_time2 = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(KusaSprite2,self).__init__()

        self.images = list()
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa0.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa1.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa2.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa3.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa4.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_kusa5.png'))
        self.index = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.image2 = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(600,0))
        

    def update(self):
        self.kusa_time += 1

        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0


        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        if self.kusa_time == 5:
            self.index += 1
            self.kusa_time = 0
        
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(200,800))


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------




#小石のクラス-------------------------------------------------------------------------
class KoishiSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    score = 0
    font = pygame.font.Font("DotGothic16-Regular.ttf",34)
    
    #小石クラスの時間
    koishi_time = 0
    koishi_speed = 5
    koishi_level = [5,15]

    koishi_speed2 = 5
    koishi_level2 = [5,15]


    #小石の場所についての変数
    koishi_x = 500
    koishi_y = 0

    koishi_x2 = 300
    koishi_y2 = 0


    koishi_rect = pygame.Rect(koishi_x,655,50,50)
    koishi_rect = pygame.Rect(koishi_x,655,50,50)

    score_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('pygame_ishiyokeyo_click_sound.mp3')
    damage_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('pygame_ishiyokeyo_damage_sound.mp3')

                

    def update(self,player_rect):

        self.koishi_y += self.koishi_speed

        
        self.koishi_rect = pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x,self.koishi_y,25,20)
        #pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,self.koishi_rect)


        self.koishi_img = pygame.image.load('koishi.png')
        self.koishi_img = pygame.transform.scale(self.koishi_img,(64,64))
        screen.blit(self.koishi_img,pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x - 20,self.koishi_y - 20,25,20))
        

        if player_rect.colliderect(self.koishi_rect):
            self.damage_sound.play()
            Heart.heart -= 1
            self.koishi_y = 0
            self.koishi_x = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed = random.randint(self.koishi_level[0],self.koishi_level[1])

        if self.koishi_y >= 800:
            self.score += 1
            self.koishi_y = 0
            self.koishi_x = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed = random.randint(self.koishi_level[0],self.koishi_level[1])
            self.score_sound.play()
    

    def update2(self,player_rect):

        self.koishi_y2 += self.koishi_speed2

        
        self.koishi_rect2 = pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x2,self.koishi_y2,25,20)
        #pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREEN,self.koishi_rect2)


        self.koishi_img2 = pygame.image.load('koishi.png')
        self.koishi_img2 = pygame.transform.scale(self.koishi_img2,(64,64))
        screen.blit(self.koishi_img2,pygame.Rect(self.koishi_x2 - 20,self.koishi_y2 - 20,25,20))
        

        if player_rect.colliderect(self.koishi_rect2):
            self.damage_sound.play()
            Heart.heart -= 1
            self.koishi_y2 = 0
            self.koishi_x2 = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed2 = random.randint(self.koishi_level2[0],self.koishi_level2[1])

        if self.koishi_y2 >= 800:
            self.score += 1
            
            self.koishi_y2 = 0
            self.koishi_x2 = random.randint(220,580)
            self.koishi_speed2 = random.randint(self.koishi_level2[0],self.koishi_level2[1])
            self.score_sound.play()
        
       

    def blit_score(self):
        #スコアのテキスト
        self.text_score = self.font.render('score = ' + str(self.score),True,WHITE)
        screen.blit(self.text_score,(30,30))

        
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

game_start = False
#ハートのクラス---------------------------------------------------
class Heart():
    game_over = False
    
    heart_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_heart.png')
    heart_img = pygame.transform.scale(heart_img,(64,64))
    font = pygame.font.Font('DotGothic16-Regular.ttf',50)
    text_HP = font.render('HP',True,WHITE)
    heart = 4

    def update(self):
        screen.blit(self.text_HP,(30,100))
        if self.heart == 4:
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(10,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(55,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(100,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(145,160))
        
        if self.heart == 3:
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(10,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(55,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(100,160))

        if self.heart == 2:
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(10,160))
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(55,160))

        if self.heart == 1:
            screen.blit(self.heart_img,(10,160))

        if self.heart == 0:
            gameover.gameowari()
            self.game_over = True
        print(Heart.game_over)

        

            

#------------------------------------------------------------------

#game overのクラス---------------------------------------------
class GameOver():
    #コンティニューボタン
    continue_button_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_continue_button.png')
    continue_button_img = pygame.transform.scale(continue_button_img,(128,128))
    continue_rect = pygame.Rect(170,550,60,60)
    #ホームボタン
    home_button_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_home_button.png')
    home_button_img = pygame.transform.scale(home_button_img,(128,128))
    home_rect = pygame.Rect(500,550,60,60)
    #ゲームオーバー
    gameover_UI_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_game_over_UI.png')
    gameover_UI_rect = gameover_UI_img.get_rect(center=gameover_UI_img.get_rect(center=(400,400)).center)
    def gameowari(self):

        screen.blit(self.gameover_UI_img,self.gameover_UI_rect)
        screen.blit(self.continue_button_img,self.continue_rect)
        screen.blit(self.home_button_img,self.home_rect)








#-------------------------------------------------------------

gameover = GameOver()





#BGM
title_BGM = True
game_BGM = False
bgm_time = 0
def bgm(title_BGM,game_BGM):
    if title_BGM == True:
        title_BGM = False
        pygame.mixer.music.load('pygame_Title_BGM.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
    
    if game_BGM == True:
        game_BGM = False
        pygame.mixer.music.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_main_BGM.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)









#プレイヤーのx座標
player_x = 335




#スプライトのオブジェクトを作ってグループ化------
#プレイヤー
player = PlayerSprite()
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group(player)

#小石
koishi = KoishiSprite()
koishi_group = pygame.sprite.Group(koishi)

#背景
kusa = KusaSprite()
kusa_group = pygame.sprite.Group(kusa)
kusa2 = KusaSprite2()
kusa_group2 = pygame.sprite.Group(kusa2)

#----------------------------------------


heart = Heart()


#線を描画---------
def draw_line():
    pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,(200,0),(200,800),3)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,(600,0),(600,800),3)

#----------------


#FPS--------
FPS = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#-----------

bg = Backgrou()

#ロゴ
logo_rect = pygame.Rect(80,50,300,200)
logo_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_logo.png')
logo_img = pygame.transform.scale(logo_img,(600,400))



#ボタン設定-------------------------------------------------
#スタートボタン
start_button_rect = pygame.Rect(300,500,200,60)
start_button_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_start_button.png')

#難易度設定
#easy
easy_button_rect = pygame.Rect(300,400,200,60)
easy_button_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_easy_button.png')
#normal
normal_button_rect = pygame.Rect(300,500,200,60)
normal_button_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_normal_button.png')
#hard
hard_button_rect = pygame.Rect(300,600,200,60)
hard_button_img = pygame.image.load('pygame_ishiyokeyo_hard_button.png')



#---------------------------------------------------------


#今どの場面か
#レベル設定（Falseならスタート画面）
select_level = False


click_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('pygame_ishiyokeyo_click_sound.mp3')
def click_button():
    click_sound.play()





game_time = 0



#メインループ=================================================
run = True
while run:
    bgm_time += 1
    game_time += 1

    if bgm_time == 1 and game_start == False:
        bgm(title_BGM,game_BGM)
    if bgm_time == 1 and game_start == True and Heart.game_over == False:
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        game_BGM = True
        bgm(title_BGM,game_BGM)
    
    

    screen.fill((0,200,0))
    if game_start == True and Heart.game_over == False:
        draw_line()

    if game_start == False:
        if select_level == False:
            screen.blit(start_button_img,start_button_rect)
            

        if select_level == True:
            screen.blit(easy_button_img,easy_button_rect)
            screen.blit(normal_button_img,normal_button_rect)
            screen.blit(hard_button_img,hard_button_rect)

        screen.blit(logo_img,logo_rect)

    
    

    #プレイヤーの当たり判定
    player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_x + 37,662,40,108)
    #pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,player_rect)

    #小石のプログラムの実行
    


    #プレイヤー
    if game_start == True and Heart.game_over == False:
        player_group.update()
        player_group.draw(screen)      

    #草
    if game_start == True and Heart.game_over == False:
        kusa_group.update()
        kusa_group.draw(screen)
        kusa_group2.update()
        kusa_group2.draw(screen)
        
        

    
    if game_start == True and Heart.game_over == False:
        koishi.update(player_rect)
        koishi.update2(player_rect)
    #背景
    if game_start == True and Heart.game_over == False:
        bg.trans()
        bg.Background_time(screen)

    if game_start == True and Heart.game_over == False:
        koishi.blit_score()
    if game_start == True and Heart.game_over == False:
        heart.update()

    '''if Heart.game_over == True:
        gameover.gameowari()'''



    #イベントの取得
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if start_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                if select_level == False and game_start == False:

                    game_time = 0
                    select_level = True
                    
                    click_button()
                    print('Start')
            if game_time >= 5:
                if easy_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    if select_level == True and game_start == False:

                        game_start = True
                        
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[0] = 3
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[1] = 10

                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[0] = 3
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[1] = 10

                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()

                        click_button()
                        print('Easy game start!')
                        bgm_time = 0
                    
                if normal_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    if select_level == True and game_start == False:
                        
                        game_start = True
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[0] = 5
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[1] = 15

                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[0] = 5
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[1] = 15

                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                        
                        click_button()
                        print('Normal game start!')
                        bgm_time = 0
                
                if hard_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    if select_level == True and game_start == False:

                        game_start = True
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[0] = 10
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level[1] = 20

                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[0] = 10
                        KoishiSprite.koishi_level2[1] = 20

                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()

                        click_button()
                        print('Hard game start!')
                        bgm_time = 0
                    

                    


    #プレイヤーのキー入力
    if game_start == True and Heart.game_over == False:
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and not player_x == 165:
            player_x -= 5
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not player_x == 520:
            player_x += 5
    

    #画面の更新とFPSの設定
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

#===========================================================


pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.game_over`はインスタンス変数だからです
`Heart.game_over`はクラス変数 (クラスにつきひとつ)

`self.game_over` に何か代入するまでは同じものを指していて
代入するとそちらにアクセスするようになります

```py
>>> class Heart:
...     go = False
...     def setgo(self, v):
...         self.go = v
...
>>> o = Heart()
>>> o.go, Heart.go
(False, False)
>>> id(o.go), id(Heart.go)
(104738733492992, 104738733492992)
>>> o.go is Heart.go
True

>>> o.setgo(True)
>>> o.go, Heart.go
(True, False)
>>> id(o.go), id(Heart.go)
(104738733493440, 104738733492992)
>>> o.go is Heart.go
False

>>> other = Heart()
>>> other.go is Heart.go
True
```

グローバル変数とローカル変数でも似たことが起きます

```py
>>> val = 123
>>> def fn():
...     print(val)
...
>>> fn()
123
>>> def fn():
...     val = 'hello'
...     print(val)
...
>>> fn()
hello
>>> val
123
```

Comment: どのように書き換えれば良いのでしょうか。（再び質問すみません）

Comment: どのように行いたいのでしょうか？ クラス変数で扱う(インスタンス変数ではない) のなら, `Heart.game_over = True`でいいし, インスタンス変数で扱うならどのようにかコードを直す必要があるでしょう

Comment: なるほど、わかりました！